# McAfee Endpoint Security Firewall blocks miracast connection to Microsoft wireless display adapter

Tags: firewall, miracast

I tried connecting my laptop with a Microsoft wireless display adapter, the connection only works if I disable my McAfee firewall.
I don't have a lot of experience/know how about firewalls, but I tried implementing the rule detailed in this article
https://success.trendmicro.com/solution/1119259-firewall-setting-configuration-for-intel-widi-miracast-in-officescan
as well as this article
https://kc.mcafee.com/corporate/index?page=content&id=KB85497&locale=en_US

but neither of them worked.

Comment: Have you disabled the Windows firewall, meaning do you have two firewalls? Is the wifi network marked perhaps as public?

Comment: @harrymc the windows firewall is not active, and the wifi is not marked as public

Comment: Try to find in the McAfee firewall a log of refused connections. I just note that the Windows Defender Firewall is just as good and less problematic.

Comment: @harrymc the "FirewallEventMonitor.txt" file is porbably what you're getting at right ?

Comment: I'm not a McAfee user (any more), so can only suggest directions.

Comment: @harrymc appreciate the help nonetheless, i'm using mcafee on this pc, since it's company policy to do so. the file i mentioned does list refused connections, but even though i already added a rule which allows the specific connection that keeps popping up when trying to connect to the adapter it is still being refused

Comment: The only idea I have is that the firewall rules you added are not complete, for example regarding the protocol and others. There might also be general settings that invalidate the rules you added. That's as far as I can go.

Comment: @harrymc thanks for the input, i feel like i'll just have to get more familiar with the topic of firewalls in general

Answer (score 0):

In order to make the connection work without disabling mcafee, you need to first figure out the ip adress of your display adapter.

You can find this by trying to connect to it with the firewall enabled, and checking the "FirewallEventMonitor.txt" file, it shows up as a blocked connection with the WUDFHost.exe application. Next you need to go into advanced settings for your firewall and manually mark this ip adress as trustworthy.

Comment: I edited your answer to make it more easily readable. The edit will be viewable once a senior community member approves it. I think you have to wait for a couple of days, but when you can please [accept your answer](https://superuser.com/help/self-answer) so that others who seek help can see that this question contains a solution. As a side note - your FW is company-mandated. If it's also company-managed, don't be surprised if you have to do this again at some point. I'd probably have a chat with the company IT guys about this.

Comment: @Peregrino69 i will, i aready set up a meeting with the admin for later today